# Button not registering touches in custom UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I tried creating a custom UIButton and then dragged a normal button to my view and set the Custom class property to be the custom UIButton class I created, then I tried to make an action by CTRL and drag, after making the IBAction outlet it wont register touches anymore. If i remove the Custom Class then touches would be fine and if I add it again, It wont register touches anymore.

**My custom button code**

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
       didSet {
           layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
           layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
       }
    }

@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var backgroundColorOnTouch: UIColor?
@IBInspectable var textColorOnTouch: UIColor?

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    invert()
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    invert()
}

func invert() -> Void {        
    layer.backgroundColor = backgroundColorOnTouch?.cgColor
    setTitleColor(textColorOnTouch, for: .normal)

    let temp = backgroundColorOnTouch
    backgroundColorOnTouch = textColorOnTouch
    textColorOnTouch = temp        
}

}
```

**When I refer to changing the custom class property I mean this:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UIButton is a UIControl and already does its own complex built-in touch detection. Your custom UIButton subclass implements `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` and thus interferes with the button's own natural touch detection.

Solution: Don't do that. You're screwing up the button.

If (as it appears) your goal is to make the button's appearance change depending on its state (e.g. normal vs. highlighted while the user is tapping it), set its appearance relative to the desired state. That is exactly what the state is for.

For example, to change the background based on the state, configure the button in advance by calling `setBackgroundImage:forState:`, for both normal and highlighted states. To change the title color based on the state, configure the button in advance by calling `setTitleColor:forState:`, for both normal and highlighted states. And so on. The button, thus configured, will then *automatically* change its background and title color as the user taps and as the user releases.